# Selecionar todos os elementos de uma array em uma variável com Regex no PHP

Tags: php, regex

Eu gostaria de fazer um regex para aplicar uma classe a cada linha com número romanos, o regex seria? `/(<li>\s*<p>$romanos\)_\-_/` ?

O documentos está assim:

```
<li>
  <p>I - blablabla</p>
</li>
<li>
  <p>II - blablabla</p>
</li>
<li>
  <p>III - blablabla</p>
</li>
```

Gostaria que ficasse assim

```
<li class="inciso">
  <p>I - blablabla</p>
</li>
<li class="inciso">
  <p>II - blablabla</p>
</li>
<li class="inciso">
  <p>III - blablabla</p>
</li>
```

Criei uma array dos números romanos

```
$romanos =  array(I,II,III,IV,V,VI,VII,VIII,IX,X,XI,XII,XIII,XIV,XV,XVI,XVII,XVIII,XIX,XX,XXI,XXII,XXIII,XXIV,XXV,XXVI,XXVII,XXVIII,XXIX,XXX,XXXI,XXXII,XXXIII,XXXIV,XXXV,XXXVI,XXXVII,XXXVIII,XXXIX);
```

Aqui está as variável do texto que procuro

```
$semClassInciso = '/   <li>
  <p>$romanos - /';
```

Aqui esta a variável do texto com a tag LI cuja class é "inciso

```
$comClassInciso = '/   <li class="inciso">
  <p>$romanos - /';
```

Aqui é o documento onde está o texto com os incisos

```
$documento = file_get_contents($arquivo);

$documento1 = preg_replace($semClassInciso, $comClassInciso , $documento);

echo  $documento1;
```

Resumindo, quero adicionar a tag `<li class="inciso">` em todas as ocorrências de números romanos que estejam no início de um parágrafo.

Comment: Não consegui entender, pode explicar melhor o que pretende?

Comment: Nas variável $semClassInciso, o que varia é o numero, tenho inciso 1, 2, 3, 4 ...., e gostaria de acrescentar a classe inciso em todas as ocorrências

Comment: Mas os números estão em romano

Comment: Inciso I, II, III

Comment: O título não condiz com o que você quer, mas pelo que entendi, tente fazer algo assim: http://ideone.com/zUZRCL

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta, vê se ficou mais claro, um pouco, mas ainda não sei como deixar mais claro o título

Comment: Veja se é algo assim que você quer fazer: http://ideone.com/7eDrPr

Comment: a explicação estava confusa para entender. Editei um trecho e adicionei um resumo que explica o que vc quer.

Comment: @qmechanik, coloquei as quais linhas que tenho no arquivo, esta é a estrutura, o script deveria ler cada linha e aplicar a classe inciso em cada linha

Comment: @AlêMoraes Tente assim: **http://ideone.com/0gZclc**, veja se funciona no seu caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta usar o [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace-callback.php) algo mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php

function adicionaTexto($matches) {
    return '<li class="inciso">' . $matches[0];
}

$documento = file_get_contents($arquivo);

$documento1 = preg_replace_callback($semClassInciso, adicionaTexto, $documento);

echo  $documento1;
```

---

Bom vou deixar a dica ai do callback pode ser útil. Você pode tentar também algo assim:

```
$re = "/(<li>)(\s*<p>[MDCLXVI]+)/"; 
$str = "<li>
  <p>I - blablabla</p>
</li>
<li>
  <p>II - blablabla</p>
</li>
<li>
  <p>III - blablabla</p>
</li>";


$subst = "<li class=\"inciso\">$2"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Um exemplo aqui -> https://regex101.com/r/dQ5oD0/2

Comment: Editei a pergunta, não estou sendo e claro, e não sei como explicar, kkk, Vê se ficou um pouco mais claro a pergunta